# What does D2 do in this schematic?

Tags: diodes, vco

Can somebody clarify what the purpose of D2 is in this schematic:

[image]

I understand that we are taking a clock input from the Sync jack to the transistor. The reset pin (4) is pulled high to Vcc, until the NPN transistor is activated (pulled high) and it then drops the pin 4 to GND through the transistor. (Can somebody please clarify if my wording is correct with this description? How could I be more clear when speaking about transistors?)

However, I do not understand what the D2 diode is supposed to do. Is it some sort of protection in the case of an incorrect input at the Sync jack? Isn't that what the de-coupling cap is for?

Comment: To be clear, I am speaking about diode D2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it D2 is to protect Q1's base emitter junction from excessive reverse voltages. The presence of C2 means the Sync input signal is AC coupled and it eliminates any DC bias, but now the Sync signal will attempt to drive base of Q1 equally positive and negative. In the positive direction the b-e junction will conduct in normal transistor operation, but on the negative excursion there would be nothing to limit the voltage if D1 were not in place.

D1 also serves to clip any negative noise pulses if they are present in the environment.

Comment: Doesn't a transistor, that is reverse biased, block current by design?

Comment: @NateHouk Only up to a point, as Dave Tweed says. The b-e junction of this type of transistor can only withstand a few volts before it breaks down. This will either cause catastrophic failure or slow degradation.

Comment: Answering my own question... I believe the answer is that it does block current by design when reverse biased, but you can exceed a "breakdown voltage" when reverse biasing that can cause current to flow despite the negative voltage on the base. This breakdown voltage is Vebo in the data sheet, which normally is around 5v.

Comment: Thank you @PeterJennings

Answer (score 1):

D2 protects Q1 from reverse bias on its B-E junction.

A typical small-signal transistor can only withstand a few volts of reverse bias before it breaks down, and an antiparallel diode limits it to about 0.7 V.

R31 limits the current into the transistor when the input is positive, and it also limits the current through the diode when the input is negative.

Comment: What does "Anti-Parallel" mean?

Comment: And what would happen if the signal was LOW and we didn't have the D2 diode? That would put us into reverse bias? And I am assuming, with too much reverse bias, the transistor can fail and allow current through? Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily damage the transistor, especially since the current is so limited, but the unwanted current would probably disrupt the circuit operation.

Comment: Doesn't a transistor, that is reverse biased, block current by design?

Comment: Not if you force the B-E junction into reverse breakdown. BTW, "antiparallel" is just shorthand for parallel diodes pointing in opposite directions. Parallel diodes would point in the same direction.

Comment: I don't see a second diode... it looks like just the 1 diode? So is that still anti-parallel? Are you counting the transistor as a sort of "diode" pointing in the opposite direction?

Comment: @NateHouk antiparallel of a pair of diodes means in parallel but pointing (conducting) the other way. The 2 diodes being D2 and the b-e junction of Q1

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on duty cycle of the incoming "hard sync", you may need the diode to provide DC restoration.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from protecting the Base from excessive negative voltage, the diode is necessary to provide equal charge and discharge paths for the coupling capacitor. Without the diode the capacitor will charge up as Base current flows into the transistor when the signal goes high, but will have no discharge path (apart from the Vbe breakdown at ~-7.5V) when it goes low. This will cause the capacitor to accumulate a negative charge, 'cutting off' the transistor with negative bias.

I simulated the sync circuit in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) with a 10V pulse waveform. Without the diode the Base and Collector waveforms looked like this:-

[image]

The capacitor quickly charged to -7.5V and stayed there, with positive pulses just reaching the Base turn on voltage of 0.6V. The transistor barely managed to get 2 pulses out before it became cut off.

With the diode in place the waveforms changed to this:-

[image]

Now when the sync signal goes low the diode clamps the Base to -0.6V and discharges the capacitor, so when the signal goes high it produces a strong Base drive and the transistor maintains full output.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “clamps the base”? And why is it clamped to -0.6v?

Comment: By 'clamps' I mean it prevents the voltage from going any lower. It is 'clamped' to ~0.6V because this is characteristic of a silicon diode. The transistor's Base-Emitter junction has a similar characteristic. https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_4.html

Comment: Understood, thank you!